# A word for somebody who tries to deflect the blame from themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for somebody who tries to shift the blame or maybe not shift the blame so much as they do something and they explain it away in a way that doesn't put it on anybody else but could easily be explained by the media or general Society  or racial issues  or outlandish explanation  such as God's will  what have you, anything but the truth that really they are at heart the one to blame the one with the issue the one with the law they are trying to explain it away like deflect the issue. It's never something to do with themselves personally anything but what the truth is.

I would say that the word is often used with the intent to be deceptive with others when you know the truth. Not liar not passing the buck perhaps justifying.

Comment: "Shift the blame" comes up in several other ELU Q&A's.  Searching the site may give you what you're looking for.  You need to add an example sentence to get more help.

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rationalize) has << **rationalize
(also rationalise)** verb [with object] 1 Attempt to explain or justify (behaviour or an attitude) with logical reasons, even if these are not appropriate. >> However, the noun 'rationalist' doesn't fit with this.

Answer (score 1):

**spin doctor** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin%20doctor))

> a person (as a political aide) responsible for ensuring that others interpret an event from a particular point of view

**apologist** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apologist))

> a person who defends or supports something (such as a religion, cause, or organization) that is being criticized or attacked by other people

Answer (score 1):

Building on Edwin Ashworth's comment, perhaps **rationalizer** (not *rationalist*) works.

OD:

> [**rationalizer**]: one who rationalizes
>
> [**rationalize**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rationalize):
>   attempt to explain or justify (behaviour or an attitude) with logical
>   reasons, even if these are not appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Scapegoater
A “scapegoater” is someone who looks for a “scapegoat” in someone else. That means they will always try to find someone else to blame for their mistakes. Often, they’ll do this to make sure they don’t take the fall for their own actions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A person to whom hypocrisy is a second nature is normally referred to as a

**hypocrite**

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypocrite?s=t

Simplicity is a virtue. Sometimes.