# word search for dramatic imperative after a party is found guilty

Tags: single-word-requests

Spouse 1 cheats on spouse 2, breaks the vows, and the whole 9 yards.

Spouse 1 is caught, spouse 2 is distraught.

Spouse 1 is reacting dramatically, says the typical : *I love you. Don't you ever question my love for you !*

Let's focus on the second part : **Don't you ever question my love for you.**

**Question :**

Is there a word that describes this kind of imperatives?

**Attempt to answer :**

Patronizing comes to mind. Is there a better word that captures the fact that spouse 1 is

- Patronizing
- Trying to shift the focus elsewhere
- Pretending to be positive by challenging valid criticism

Thank you.

EDITS:

I have been pointed to the following stack-exchange questions, but they are not satisfactory. Here are my responses to each of the questions.

1. [A word for somebody who tries to deflect the blame from themselves](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385347/a-word-for-somebody-who-tries-to-deflect-the-blame-from-themselves)

The answers are :

1.1 Rationalization - but no, that does not capture the imperative/commanding/almost disciplining nature of "don't you dare...".

1.2 Apologizing - but no, that does not capture the imperative nature as well.

1.3 Spin Doctoring - spinning is rather general in nature, still does not capture my points.

2. [What's a word that means deflect blame?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/485330/whats-a-word-that-means-deflect-blame)

The answers are scapegoating or implicating. But spouse 1 is **not** blaming spouse 2. Instead the situation is to draw attention off from the cheating and to spouse 1's *proclaimed love*. The method used is similar to the way a parent would discipline a child : "don't you dare watch TV now".

3. [Children caught by an adult doing something wrong, relaying the blame onto each other](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156292/children-caught-by-an-adult-doing-something-wrong-relaying-the-blame-onto-each)

This answer contains "blame shifting". But the situation i mentioned does not imply even a potential blamable event. Spouse 2 has not yet explicitly questioned the love of spouse 1. So spouse 1 is also **not** directly saying **"How dare you question my love?"**.

Spouse 2's reaction is more pre-emptive in nature. But then again, spouse 2 has not explicitly pulled the "What about ..." card. Spouse 2 has not yet stated "But you are questioning my love - what about that?". If the last sentence was stated, then we could use words like table turning, spin doctoring, may be even blame shifting.

But I want to capture the imperative nature of the sentence, the patronizing approach (as noted by the commenter Weather Vane, the lack of the word "please" is important) attempt to almost discipline spouse 2, as if spouse 2 is a child overstepping their boundary set by spouse 1 by questioning the love of spouse 1.

4. [What is the word that means to accuse someone of a crime, to divert attention from the guilt of the accuser](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255839/what-is-the-word-that-means-to-accuse-someone-of-a-crime-to-divert-attention-fr)

Among the answers here, demagogy, imputing, or even projection may sound applicable - but still missing the imperative nature of Spouse 1's statement.

So, a bit more specific, target vocabulary is what I am after.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a *defensive measure*.

Comment: Does the word defensive measure convey the patronizing part? Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't call the move patronising at all. The [fallacious argument](https://thebestschools.org/magazine/15-logical-fallacies-know/) is perhaps *appeal to pity* (appeal to emotion), or perhaps *red herring*.

Comment: 'Don't you ever question my love for you.' sounds far less tender than other alternatives available nowadays, IMO. It's unhedged (no 'Please' for a start). And thus I'm left questioning the sincerity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is the essence i want to capture. it's pretentious. Spouse 1 is trying to discipline spouse 2 as a child, even tho spouse 1 is the cause of the problem. Spouse 1 is trying to "straighten up" spouse 2 - and police the thoughts of spouse 2

Comment: I suppose that many idioms might apply: expressing "faux outrage", setting up a "straw man" argument, "gaslighting", "turning the tables", etc.

Comment: It sounds like a threat to me.